# How to load data from remote url after navigating screen?

Tags: react-native

I have created an app with react native. This app contains 3 screens and 1 menu.

Screen 1: Homepage (list of contents: user info, photo, membership date and etc)
Screen 2: User details (when tap, user screen loaded and shows movies user already have)
Screen 3: Search user

and a Menu opens from left to right.

I have coded this without using navigation but now i would like to add navigation. However, when i coded this, i used a root component which handles all url requests and shows te correct screen. For example when app first starts it loads homescreen and uses `this.setState({ page: 'home', loading: true })` and under `render()` i check the `this.state.page` to get which screen to show. There are 2 setState's (first is before making request and second is after making request). After first call, i show the page but of course data is not loaded and you see only the design. After request returns with some data, render() runs again but this time with data.

How can i move this to navigation? I mean i couldn't find a way to do it. I don't want to mess the code and never used navigation before. I don't want to show any tab bar or top bar. I just want to do this handling press. Tab bar and top bar is not part of my design.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and unclear about what your problem really is. Please try to make it more clear and add [mcve] of your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch your data in `componentDidMount()`. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) is the documentation.

For emxemple, when you switch to your page User details, your component will mount. At first you let `loading` at true in your state. In `componentDidMount()` you call your function to fetch your data. When you received your data, you set `loading` to false and you show your informations.

Comment: componentDidMount() does not run only if i setState() let's say i need to render another data in same screen and setting loading: true but componentDidMount only fires once